# Constructor Not Assigning Values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a few objects in Matlab. I am used to programming in Java, but being able to do this in Matlab would be beneficial for my research.

So, I have a particular class:

```
classdef Lifter < handle


properties

    weightClass = 0;
    mean = 0;
    var = 0;
    nation = '';

end

methods

    function Lifter = Lifter(weightClass,mean,var,nation) %Constructor

        Lifter.weightClass = weightClass;
        Lifter.mean = mean;
        Lifter.var = var;
        Lifter.nation = nation;

    end

    function set.weightClass(this,weightClass)
    end       
    function set.mean(this,mean)
    end       
    function set.var(this,var)
    end       
    function set.nation(this,nation)
    end

    function value = get.weightClass(this)
        value = this.weightClass;
    end
    function value = get.mean(this)
        value = this.mean;
    end       
    function var = get.var(this)
        var = this.mean;
    end   
    function nation = get.nation(this)
        nation = this.nation;
    end

end
```

end

Pretty standard, doesn't really do much.

So, in another page, I have:

```
function Competition()

Lifter1 = Lifter(56,1,1,'USA')

end
```

However, running this gives:

```
Lifter1 = 

Lifter with properties:

weightClass: 0
       mean: 0
        var: 0
     nation: ''
```

Any help to figure out why this values are not being initialized correctly from the constructor would be very helpful.

Also, an example of how to actually call a setter or getter method on my Lifter1 object would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those setters are for *dependent* properties (declared as `properties(Dependent)`). But also, your setters are not implemented (empty), which means that all your property assignments won't do anything. Which means that the properties stay with the default values declared in the `properties` section.

*Later Edit*

If I would have to implement the class, I'd do it like in the following code:

```
    classdef Lifter < handle


            % --- PUBLIC SECTION ---

            properties(Dependent)

                    weight_class;
            end;


            methods

                    function obj = Lifter(weight_class)
                            obj.weight_class = weight_class;
                    end;

                    function set.weight_class(obj, weight_class)
                            if ~isa(obj, 'Lifter') ...
                            || ~isscalar(obj) ...
                            || ~isvalid(obj)
                                    error('Lifter:Arg', '"obj" must be a scalar valid handle object of class "Lifter".');
                            elseif ~isnumeric(weight_class) ...
                            || ~isscalar(weight_class) ...
                            || ~isreal(weight_class) ...
                            || (weight_class <= 0) % + other value tests
                                    error('Lifter:Arg', '"weight_class" must be a numeric positive scalar.');
                            else
                                    obj.weight_class_ = double(weight_class);
                            end;
                    end;

                    function val = get.weight_class(obj)
                            val = obj.weight_class_;
                    end;
            end;


            % --- PRIVATE SECTION ---

            properties(Access=private)

                    weight_class_;

            end;

    end
```

The code for the rest of the properties is similar. Test with:

```
    a = Lifter(100);         % Constructor + setter call
    a.weight_class = 75;     % Setter call
    disp(a.weight_class);    % Getter call
    a.weight_class = '85';   % Setter call with wrong value
```

Comment: Off topic question - is it really necessary to check that `obj` is a `Lifter` object in the `set.weight_class` method? Is it possible for MATLAB to execute this method with `obj` being a different object. As you appear to do, I also do a lot of type and value checking in my methods. `assert` is your friend.

Comment: @b3. In my opinion it is necessary. The same method will be called when the object is passed as the second argument and the numeric arg is the first (because the correct method is chosen by the most dominant class in the arg list, and not by the first arg class). In MATLAB `assert` or `if`/`error` is a matter of taste I think (as opposed to C, where it can be disabled by pre-processor defines).

Comment: Interesting about how the method is chosen! Makes sense now why you'd need to check the object type. For setters and getters though I couldn't get the those methods to fire except by obj.prop = value so I don't think the check is necessary in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your setters and getters should not contain dots (although I agree it would be more elegant your way if it worked):

```
function set.weightClass(this,weightClass)
end
```

Could be (should be) :

```
function set_weightClass(this,weightClass)
end
```

If I replace all of them, it works properly.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much. Been searching on the internet, I came across guides that showed:

"function set.weightClass(this,weightClass)"

Perhaps this was only if it was a Value class? 

Either way, thanks very much.

Comment: @user43395 Sorry for insisting, but `set.weightClass` is the setter for a *dependent* property (the only difference between value and handle classes being that the first returns the modified object, while the second doesn't): http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html